# regular expression capture the string in the thrid bracket

Tags: regex, vb.net

Hello Thanks to those who all help!

I have a this statement:

> SELECT DISTINCT [SAS_Tableau].[dbo].[XFRACAS_iMRO_ToBeImported].[EQUIP_EQUIPMENT_NUM], [SAS_Tableau].[dbo].[XFRACAS_iMRO_ToBeImported].[EQUIP_MATERIAL_NUM], [SAS_Tableau].[dbo].[XFRACAS_iMRO_ToBeImported].[EQUIP_MATERIAL_TEXT],

and so on... each time it be in these brackets only `[String]`

I would like to only grab `EQUIP_EQUIPMENT_NUM` and `EQUIP_MATERIAL_NUM` and `EQUIP_MATERIAL_TEXT`

This is the Regex I tried but does not work `(?<=]\.\[).*?(?=].)(?=],)`

Please help!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can omit this positive lookahead `(?=].)` as the one after it already asserts a comma. The comma  is more specific than the dot, which will match any character except a newline.

Then using a negated character class `[^` to not cross the `[]` boundaries:

```
(?<=\.\[)[^][]*(?=],)
```

See a [.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5c.%5c%5b%29%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%28%3f%3d%5d%2c%29&i=SELECT+DISTINCT+%5bSAS_Tableau%5d.%5bdbo%5d.%5bXFRACAS_iMRO_ToBeImported%5d.%5bEQUIP_EQUIPMENT_NUM%5d%2c+%5bSAS_Tableau%5d.%5bdbo%5d.%5bXFRACAS_iMRO_ToBeImported%5d.%5bEQUIP_MATERIAL_NUM%5d%2c+%5bSAS_Tableau%5d.%5bdbo%5d.%5bXFRACAS_iMRO_ToBeImported%5d.%5bEQUIP_MATERIAL_TEXT%5d%2c)